# Error in JCL installation into Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, jedi, jedi-code-library, delphi-10-seattle

I  am trying to install JCL/JVCL into Delphi-10-Seattle

I got the following Error:

> Using Embarcadero RAD Studio 10 Seattle Embarcadero Delphi for Win32
>   compiler version 30.0...
>   E:\Delphi-10\Jedi\jcl\source\common\JclSysUtils.pas(3034) Error: E2010
>   Incompatible types: 'TJclWaitResult' and 'TWaitResult'
>
> JclInstall.pas(2264) Fatal: F2063 Could not compile used unit
>   'JclSysUtils.pas'

Line 3034 in 'JclSysUtils.pas' is:

```
if (ProcessEvent.WaitForever = {$IFDEF RTL280_UP}TJclWaitResult.{$ENDIF RTL280_UP}wrSignaled) and not GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessEvent.Handle, Result) then Result := $FFFFFFFF;
```

I tried to post in the Jedi mailing list but that hasn't been touched in years.

Where can I get a fix?

Comment: You did not tell us what version you are installing. Did you take the latest revision from the repo? Does it state support for the compiler that you are using?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version JCL-2.7.0.5676. The Install text shows Delphi 10 compatibility.

Comment: It is not Delphi 10. It is Delphi 10 Seattle. The next version will also be 10, but with a different city.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK. But right now, it is the only Delphi 10 issued.

Comment: As I understand the latest version of JCL is something like 2.8.0.5677 Try to get the latest sources from [https://github.com/project-jedi](https://github.com/project-jedi) (jcl, jvcl and jedi) Unfortunately I have no D10 to check them but for D2007, DXE7 and DXE8 it was compiled without problems. @DevidHeffernan I guess that the asker uses official JEDI installer and if it founds Delphi version then it supports Delphi version.

Comment: @Chuck The name is Delphi 10 Seattle. This question will exist in the future.

Comment: @Chuck Apparently you didn't download the latest. Get the latest from the repo.

Comment: The version I downloaded is latest released version. The 2.8 that Abelisto mentions is available only in the dailies, and is considered unstable.

Comment: Well, then you have to wait for the next stable release ... :o)

Comment: In case if you are using commercial (Delphi) and OpenSource (JCL) products you have to be ready for some time lag. Use previouse Delphi release with stable JCL or wait for stable JCL for latest Delphi :) Good luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the GetIt Package Manager integrated in your RadStudio IDE to download JCL.

Comment: Finally an answer that actually solves my problem. Thank You Tommy.

Comment: ALso JVCL can be installed in the same way after restarting Delphi

Comment: GetIt search finds nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The version that you downloaded does not support Seattle. You will need to download the latest version from the repo.

Comment: This answer will become as outdated in several days (I hope :)

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks, but the first sentence is clearly accurate, and the second will solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan would you please point me to that repo url ? I try to find on GetIt  with key word `jcl` or `jvcl` it said no result found. I use Delphi 10.1 starter.

Comment: @Bianca It's hosted on github these days

Comment: repos are at https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl and https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl