# Installing JVCL into Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, jvcl, delphi-10-seattle

When trying to install JCL and JVCL into Delphi 10 Seattle using the GetIt Package Manager I get an error:

"Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 (6.1.7601)

JVCL 3.50.0.0

[Generating: Packages]
Generating packages for D15
    Loaded template.dpk
    Loaded template.dproj
    Loaded template.rc
[Compiling: Packages]
[Compiling: JvCore150.bpl]
Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 22.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\CatalogRepository\JEDIVisualComponentLibraryJVCL-3.49\Common\jvcl.inc(26) Fatal: F1026 File not found: 'jedi\jedi.inc'
"

JCL version is 2.8.0 that is available via GetIt Package Manager

This question has some resemblance with [Error in JCL installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671970/error-in-jcl-installation-into-delphi-10-seattle)

Comment: Updated with error text.

Comment: I don't think the dv was harsh. That's how the voting works. Now that your edit addresses  my criticisms, I can change my voting. Looks like the dreaded jedi.inc issue that has been discussed over and over on the Google+ dev group.

Comment: Some background. I have inherited a project that uses jedi, and I don't have a clue what components that has been used and for what.

Comment: Good luck untangling that! My experience with JEDI was that bringing in even one component forced to you also take an epic amount of other code that you did not use.

Comment: There are a lot of unit-to-unit coupling problems with the Jedi codebase. It's hard to slurp one unit of it into your app and avoid coupling the whole thing, indirectly. That being said, the installer generally works for me, when I just download it.  On Delphi 10 Seattle I downloaded JEDI JCL+JVCL with GetIt and it worked fine first try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeded to install JCL and JVCL by download a ziped version (JVCL349CompleteJCL27-Build5676.zip) containing both JCL and JCVL from http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/

The problem I had seams to relate to multible installations of Delphi and several versions of JCL in the path. If I just installed for DX, it worked fine :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Uncheck other versions of delphi - The JCL installer defaults to installing into EVERY version of Delphi, not just Delphi 10 Seattle. You have to page by page and uncheck the main root tree item option on each page.
   [image]
2. Make sure you don't have any other Jedi stuff linked implicitly into other packages you have installed.
3. Make sure none of the folders in your Library Path contains another copy (probably older and out of date) of jvcl.inc or jedi.inc files, or any other Jedi JCL or JVCL source or dcu files.
4. Clean up and remove old/stale DCP/DCU files.
5. If you want to attempt a manual repair of the package settings, open the package source JvCore.dpk  from the packages folder beneath `C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\CatalogRepository\JEDIVisualComponentLibraryJVCL-3.49\` and try to manually add to the search path the `Common` and `Include` folders that contain these two files.
6. After manual repairs, try manually restarting the installer main executable, probably named `Install.bat`

If none of those work, then I suspect that the problem is that the Repository folder is a pretty long path name, and the resulting library path name may be too long for something inside the JCL installer or the DCC32 command line compiler. In such a case, I would recommend removing anything you can from your library path before you start, install JCL+JVCL and then restore your library path to its former really-long value.

Comment: I do need to keep older versions installed as I have other applications for Delphi and Delphi XE5 that uses them. I will check on the long path though, as the path is rather long.

Comment: These older versions should not be in your Delphi 10 Library Path though.  If you just copied your library path up from one version of Delphi to the next, you'll have a mess on your hands

Comment: Thanks Warren . I will try to remove the old ones with a path override in Delphi 10.

Comment: GetItPackage manager does all the complex work for you, use it!

Comment: The OP has problems because All Getit does is run the installer, which CAN FAIL if your working environment is polluted by other old copies.  The installer launched from 10 Seattle launches a Vanilla JCL+JVCL install that will detect OTHER delphi versions and try to install into them too. It can FAIL if any of those other versions have a prior version or some partial content (a few old JCL units).

Comment: This worked for me, thanks @Warren. I had JVCL 3.49 installed on XE3 and was trying to use the GetIt Package Manager to install v3.50 into 10 Seattle. It failed. So I completely removed JCL and JVCL from both XE3 and 10 Seattle, and ran the GetIt Package Manager install again, for both XE3 and 10 Seattle. This time it went through.

Answer (score 1):

> git clone git://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl.git jvcl
>   ```

This will get you the JVCL repository. **You also need the JCL** https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl

### How to install

1. Install the JCL https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl
2. Start the **jvcl\install.bat**

JCL:

> git clone git://github.com/project-jedi/jcl.git jcl
>   cd jcl
>   git submodule update --init
>   ```

This will get you the JCL repository **and initializes the submodule that contains the jedi.inc and kylix.inc files.**

### How to install

Start the **jcl\install.bat**

Comment: Don't I need to have git installed to do that?

Comment: You can download just a zip file and unzip it and run it but this whole answer is moot since GetIt already installed the files you need, you may just want to fix your issue and re-run the install.bat that it has already placed on your system, inside C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\CatalogRepository\JEDIVisualComponentLibraryJVCL-3.49\

Comment: I give -1 for this answer as it is very confusing. Author might want to re-read the post and make appropriate corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetIt Package Manager integrated in your RadStudio IDE to download JCL and JVCL, check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671970/error-in-jcl-installation-into-delphi-10-seattle).

Finally a headeachless way to install JVCL!

Answer (score -1):

Get JCL and JVCL from the source. Uncheck all no installed compilers.
This works for Embardadero 10.1 Berlin! (24)
(you could download the zip from this place)

https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl

https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl